# Using pytest's parametrize, how can I skip the remaining tests if one test case fails?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I'm using [`pytest.mark.parametrize`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html) to feed increasingly long inputs into a rather slow test function, like so:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('data', [
    b'ab',
    b'xyz'*1000,
    b'12345'*1024**2,
    ... # etc
])
def test_compression(data):
    ... # compress the data
    ... # decompress the data
    assert decompressed_data == data
```

Because compressing large amounts of data takes a long time, I'd like to skip all the remaining tests after one fails. For example if the test fails with the input `b'ab'` (the first one), `b'xyz'*1000` and `b'12345'*1024**2` and all other parametrizations should be skipped (or xfail without being executed).

I know it's possible to attach marks to individual parametrizations like so:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_input,expected", [
    ("3+5", 8),
    ("2+4", 6),
    pytest.param("6*9", 42, marks=pytest.mark.xfail),
])
```

But I don't know how I could *conditionally* apply those marks depending on the status of the previous test case. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Does `pytest -x` not work in this case? https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html?highlight=-x#stopping-after-the-first-or-n-failures

Comment: @tpaskowski The thing is that I have multiple compression algorithms to test, and I don't want to abort without testing all of them. Seeing which tests pass and which don't gives me more context about the problem; for example if *all* compression algorithms fail then I can assume that the problem is somewhere in my `DataCompressor` base class. That's why I want to skip only these specific tests, not my entire test suite.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Marks are evaluated before the tests are executed, so there's no way to pass some kind of declarative mark (like `skipif`) that depends on other tests results. You can apply custom test skipping logic in hooks, though. Modifying the [incremental testing - test steps](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#incremental-testing-test-steps) recipe from `pytest` docs:

```
# conftest.py
import pytest

def pytest_sessionstart(session):
    session.failednames = set()

def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    if call.excinfo is not None:
        item.session.failednames.add(item.originalname)

def pytest_runtest_setup(item):
    if item.originalname in item.session.failednames:
        pytest.skip("previous test failed (%s)" % item.name)  # or use pytest.xfail like in the other answer
```

Example test

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('i', range(10))
def test_spam(i):
    assert i != 3
```

yields:

```
=================================== test session starts ===================================
collected 10 items

test_spam.py::test_spam[0] PASSED
test_spam.py::test_spam[1] PASSED
test_spam.py::test_spam[2] PASSED
test_spam.py::test_spam[3] FAILED
test_spam.py::test_spam[4] SKIPPED
test_spam.py::test_spam[5] SKIPPED
test_spam.py::test_spam[6] SKIPPED
test_spam.py::test_spam[7] SKIPPED
test_spam.py::test_spam[8] SKIPPED
test_spam.py::test_spam[9] SKIPPED

========================================= FAILURES ========================================
_______________________________________ test_spam[3] ______________________________________

i = 3

    @pytest.mark.parametrize('i', range(10))
    def test_spam(i):
>       assert i != 3
E       assert 3 != 3

test_spam.py:5: AssertionError
====================== 1 failed, 3 passed, 6 skipped in 0.06 seconds ======================
```

#### Edit: working with custom markers

```
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    markers = {marker.name for marker in item.iter_markers()}
    if call.excinfo is not None and 'skiprest' in markers:
        item.session.failednames.add(item.originalname)

def pytest_runtest_setup(item):
    markers = {marker.name for marker in item.iter_markers()}
    if item.originalname in item.session.failednames and 'skiprest' in markers:
        pytest.skip(item.name)
```

Usage:

```
@pytest.mark.skiprest
@pytest.mark.parametrize('somearg', ['a', 'b', 'c'])
def test_marked(somearg):
    ...
```

Comment: This looks promising, but I understand it currently applies to *all* parametrized tests in my entire test suite. Is there a way to turn on the skipping for specific tests only? Maybe by attaching a custom mark to those tests?

Comment: Sure, just add another check for marker present in the hook logic if you want to skip only marked tests; see updated answer for an example.

Comment: @hoefling Apparently this custom markers example no longer works with current version of pytest because 'failednames' is no longer present.

Comment: @sorin that‘s the custom attribute set on session in session init hookimpl at the beginning of the example. Do you set it in your code?

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: I adapted my solution to the accepted one by usint `pytest.skip` in the fixture.

The following hack could solve your problem. The fake test function `test_compression` fails always, but is only executed once. But it requires that you add the check of `alrady_failed` fixture in your test function:

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def skip_if_already_failed(request, failed=set()):
    key = request.node.name.split("[")[0]
    failed_before = request.session.testsfailed
    if key in failed:
        pytest.skip("previous test {} failed".format(key))
    yield
    failed_after = request.session.testsfailed
    if failed_before != failed_after:
        failed.add(key)


@pytest.mark.parametrize("data", [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
def test_compression(data, skip_if_already_failed):
    assert data < 3
```

And this is the output:

```
$ py.test -v sopytest.py
================================== test session starts ==================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.6, pytest-3.8.0, py-1.6.0, pluggy-0.7.1 -- ...
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: ..., inifile:
collected 6 items

sopytest.py::test_compression[1] PASSED                                           [ 16%]
sopytest.py::test_compression[2] PASSED                                           [ 33%]
sopytest.py::test_compression[3] FAILED                                           [ 50%]
sopytest.py::test_compression[4] SKIPPED                                          [ 66%]
sopytest.py::test_compression[5] SKIPPED                                          [ 83%]
sopytest.py::test_compression[6] SKIPPED                                          [100%]

======================================= FAILURES ========================================
__________________________________ test_compression[3] __________________________________

data = 3, skip_if_already_failed = None

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("data", [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
    def test_compression(data, skip_if_already_failed):
>       assert data < 3
E       assert 3 < 3

sopytest.py:18: AssertionError
===================== 1 failed, 2 passed, 3 skipped in 0.08 seconds =====================
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is not valid anymore, `item.session` doesn't have `failednames` param.

Inspired by https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#incremental-testing-test-steps

Just one more solution that is very close to the accepted one:

`conftest.py`

```py
MARKER_SKIPREST = "skiprest"
MARKER_PARAMETRIZE = "parametrize"

_failed_parametrized_tests = set()  # History of failed tests

def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    """Memorizes names of failed Parametrized tests"""
    marker_names = {marker.name for marker in item.iter_markers()}
    if {MARKER_SKIPREST, MARKER_PARAMETRIZE}.issubset(marker_names):
        if call.excinfo is not None:
            _failed_parametrized_tests.add(item.originalname)


def pytest_runtest_setup(item):
    """Check if the test has already failed with other param.
    If yes - xfail this test"""
    marker_names = {marker.name for marker in item.iter_markers()}
    if {MARKER_SKIPREST, MARKER_PARAMETRIZE}.issubset(marker_names):
        if item.originalname in _failed_parametrized_tests:
            pytest.xfail("Previous test failed")
```

`setup.cfg`

```
[tool:pytest]
markers =
    skiprest: Skip rest of params in parametrized test if one test one of the tests in the sequence has failed.
```

`test_?.py`

```py
pytest.mark.skiprest
pytest.mark.parametrize('data', [
    b'ab',
    b'xyz'*1000,
    b'12345'*1024**2,
    ... # etc
])
def test_compression(data):
   ...
```

Comment: The `failednames` is a custom attribute that is set in the session init hookimpl at the beginning of my example. It‘s not part of pytest itself.